Best way to repair loose outlet box
What's the best way to repair this loose outlet box? This is an outlet + switch for the garbage disposal in the kitchen. The whole box is loose inside the wall. The house was built in 1943.

It seems that it has already been installed with madison straps, but is still completely loose in the wall.


"Best" is a matter of prerogative and what you have on hand. Here are a few ideas.

Clean up the dust and embed it in spray foam.

Clean up the dust and embed it in setting-type joint compound as you repair the surrounding area.

Dismount it and install a backing block behind, or above and below.

Replace it with an old work box that suits the opening.



Thanks. The first two options did occur to me, but I wasn't convinced they would actually work. Option 3 seems the most reliable option, frankly. As for option 4 are there actually boxes that come in slightly different sizes? I wasn't aware of that.

Well, different manufacturers use different types of flanges and clamping mechanisms. You'll have to see what's sold where you are.

I ended up adding a backing block behind the box. I may end up replacing the box because the alignment of the switch and the plug isn't pretty, but for the moment the main problem of the looseness is definitely solved. Thanks!

With the power off, remove the outlet and switch and install madison straps.
If you don't know how to use them, there are plenty of examples on YouTube.

Thanks. It seems that it has already been installed with madison straps but is still completely loose. I've added another picture.
